# Multiple JKS keystores on one JVM with Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, keystore, jks

I have multiple keystores and I would like the JVM to use all of them without adding extra code (the way it works with one keystore using vm options).

This JVM is going to run on Cloud Foundry and Im going to setup a number of keystore services and bind them all to my app (JVM).

Is this possible? Does cloud foundry does anything special to make this possible? I heard something about CF packing them into some zip file (maybe merges them into one keystore)

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a Java application to cloud foundry the java build pack will run and will take care of configuring the JVM JKS store. You can read more about this at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack

If you would like to use multiple JKS files I recommend you store these files inside your .jar or .war then read them from the classpath and configure your SSL context as you like.

If must you can modify the Java Buildpack (last resort) to automatically install your JKS files wherever you please in the container. You might want to do a `cf ssh` into a running container and explore the filesystem layout there to see how you can accomplish what you want.

Comment: You can also drop a `.profile` file into the root of your JAR/WAR.  This script will be executed and you can do things like adjust the default keystore/truststore by running `keytool`.  I would only suggest doing this as a second-to-last resort, before forking and creating a custom JBP.  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile

Comment: @DanielMikusa .profile not working anymore in the new version of CF see 'Note: The Java buildpack does not support pre-runtime hooks.' https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html

Comment: @hans That's not true. The docs are wrong. I've asked them to be correct a couple times, but it's still listed incorrectly. As of me writing this, `.profile` scripts work with all buildpacks (it's not up to the individual buildpack to support them, it's the platform) and I have heard no plans about them being discontinued.

Comment: @DanielMikusa for us it does not work :-/ might depend on the version of PCF. We tried it with `.profile` in the root and under resources without any success.

Comment: Try running `jar tf <jar-file>` and confirm that `.profile` is at the root of your JAR/WAR file. It must be at the root of the files that get uploaded.

Comment: Check what you have in the file. Try something very simple like `echo 'hello'` and confirm that works before doing anything more complicated. If the file is in the correct place, it should be automatically sourced. You can also run `cf ssh app-name -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"` and that is the same as what will happen when your app starts, so the `.profile` file should be source. That can be helpful for debugging as well.

Comment: Placing the file unter `src/main/resources` should be enough if [this article](https://pvtl.force.com/s/article/How-to-tell-Application-Containers-Running-Java-Apps-to-Trust-Self-Signed-Certs-or-a-Private-or-Internal-CA) is correct?

Comment: @DanielMikusa you are right! The problem was the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin which repackages the jar to make it executable so the `.profile` file from `src/main/resources/ did not to into the root folder! The solution was to use the `exec-maven-plugin` to copy the file to the jar after the build step via `jar -uvf target/app.jar .profile`